# how to change the headers of a list exported to excel?

Tags: excel

I want to use the sharepoint 2013 feature exporting to excel from a list but I want to change the name of the fields, how can it be done?

Comment: did you check this one...this is creating the csv file using the powershell...http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html

Comment: At last I did it this way but in an asp .net page, your solution is easier to update but you got to have installed the sharepoint locally, my client doesn't have it so I will have to use both solutions, thanks.